# Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST' :(

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, axios

The SOLUTION is to specify the proxy in vite config (in my case) but not in the package.json

To clarify things:
1)I tested my code in Postman it worked!
2)The request that I am sending is grammatically and logically correct!
3)if i comment the useEffect the issue is gone (but thats not solution)
4)in the example, value of ${projectId} is equal to ping-pong-game (so the link is correct)
5)back & front are running on the same port 8000
package.json (front)

> "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",

the code -> https://github.com/vovafish/personal-site

back-end request:
[image]

front-end:
[image]

postman:
[image]

in the browser:
[image]

for the smart head who keeps saying that front the same port, her ya go:
(it doesnt work this way)
[image]

Comment: Frontend is trying to GET on `localhost:5173` that’s why. Did you try to add a `baseUri` to axios?

Comment: but i specified for the front-end to run on 8000 in the package.json. (  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",) so i dont think this isthe case

Comment: Have a look to your picture « in the browser ». The url is on it. So yes, this is the case

Comment: The test in Postman is irrelevant.  In Postman the URL being requested specifies port 8000, in the browser it's clearly specifying port 5173.  These are different URLs.

Comment: but they both run on the same origin 8000 cuz i specified it in the package.json

Comment: @sammy: That's all well and good, but the information shown in the question tells a different story.  You're unlikely to convince us that the "5173" we see in the image you've shown us *actually says* "8000".  Now is a good time to stop insisting that you must be correct and can't possibly have made a mistake and start debugging.

Comment: Please for testing purpose, try to replace the axios line by: `axios.get("localhost:8000/yourUri`)

Comment: did, check the last image

Comment: The last image is still not pointing out the problem…

Comment: @sammy: Are you now trying to convince us that "localhost:8000" and "localhost:8000/api/projects/ping-pong-game" are in no way different from one another?  Because they are.  We can tell they are.  By looking at them.  I'm afraid you're still stuck in a loop of insisting that you must be right.  This is counter-productive to solving the problem.  Focusing on the actual technical problem... What is the port number of the page loaded in the browser which makes the request?  If it's different than the port of the API then you'll need to specify the port in the axios request.

Comment: ok ive changed the get request as you suggested above to (`axios.get(
        `localhost:8000/api/projects/${projectId}`
      );`) but  i still get the same error.

Comment: @sammy: When you debug that request, in the browser's debugging tools (on the Network tab) what is the full and complete URL being requested?

Comment: from the console: (url: "localhost:8000/api/projects/ping-pong-game")

Comment: did you mean this? if so I still have the issue

Comment: @sammy: What is outputting the exact text *(url: "localhost:8000/api/projects/ping-pong-game")* to the console?  That exact text, by itself, doesn't look like any standard messaging from the browser.  Why is it missing the URL protocol?  Check the network tab and get the **complete** URL from the actual request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your project is made of vite.

Vite doesn't use the proxy setting in your `package.json`, but instead uses a `vite.config.js` file to configure the proxy.

To fix this, you can try this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8000",
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    },
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: ["./src/setupTests.ts"],
  },
});
```

Comment: i did restart the server, vscode and my pc

Comment: what about browser cache?

Comment: nah still the same

Comment: i tried it still gives me the same result even after I restarted both front-end back and vscode

Comment: did you update your vite config file in my current answer?

Comment: yeah i just copied your answer

Comment: dunno why and how but after coping and pasting eventually your code turned into solution.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that your code is working now. Sometimes copying and pasting can fix some syntax errors or typos that are hard to spot.